# Covariance matrix not calculated when fitting gaussians?

Tags: python, software, astropy

[image]

So I am using Astropy's basic **models.Gaussian1D** model and a **fitter = fitting.LevMarLSQfitter()** to fit 3 Gaussian pulses with some added random noise. The fit is good, but when I type

**fitter.fit_info**, according to  [documentation](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.fitting.LevMarLSQFitter.html) here, it should automatically calculate covariance matrix and add it to the fit_info, but it doesn't, **fit_info['param_cov']** is simply **None**. What is going on?

Comment: Does [this code](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/cc2458b9ab3ea2af191acb5cc0ea1789e8d2a73f/astropy/modeling/fitting.py#L895) shed any light?

Comment: The documentations says: "Parameters calc_uncertainties bool
If the covarience matrix should be computed and set in the fit_info. Default: False" 
  https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.fitting.LevMarLSQFitter.html

Answer (score 3):

You must explicitly request uncertainties.

`fitter = fitting.LevMarLSQfitter(calc_uncertainties=True)`

Read the docs:
https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.fitting.LevMarLSQFitter.html

Comment: It's a perfectly clear, concise answer. I added a link to the documentation, which is quite clear too.